# Using context in fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-context

I am a beginner in Android. Here, trying to add a list view to my project where fragments are used for navigation drawer. Hence, I am stuck with following errors. Below is my activity code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Menu1 extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<Property> rentalProperties = new ArrayList<>();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("All");
        //create property elements

    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_all);

        //create our property elements
        rentalProperties.add(new Property(10, "Smith Street", "Sydney", "NSW", "A large 3 bedroom apartment right in the heart of Sydney! A rare find, with 3 bedrooms and a secured car park.", 450.00, "property_image_1", 3, 1, 1, false));
        rentalProperties.add(new Property(66, "King Street", "Sydney", "NSW", "A fully furnished studio apartment overlooking the harbour. Minutes from the CBD and next to transport, this is a perfect set-up for city living.", 320.00, "property_image_2", 1, 1, 1, false));
        rentalProperties.add(new Property(1, "Liverpool Road", "Liverpool", "NSW", "A standard 3 bedroom house in the suburbs. With room for several cars and right next to shops this is perfect for new families.", 360.00, "property_image_3", 3, 2, 2, true));
        rentalProperties.add(new Property(567, "Sunny Street", "Gold Coast", "QLD", "Come and see this amazing studio apartment in the heart of the gold coast, featuring stunning waterfront views.", 360.00, "property_image_4" , 1, 1, 1, false));

        //create our new array adapter
        ArrayAdapter<Property> adapter = new propertyArrayAdapter(this, 0, rentalProperties);

        //Find list view and bind it with the custom adapter
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //add event listener so we can handle clicks
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener adapterViewListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Property property = rentalProperties.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Menu1.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("streetNumber", property.getStreetNumber());
                intent.putExtra("streetName", property.getStreetName());
                intent.putExtra("suburb", property.getSuburb());
                intent.putExtra("state", property.getState());
                intent.putExtra("image", property.getImage());

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
            }
        };
        //set the listener to the list view
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(adapterViewListener);


    }


}
```

There is three errors shown, they are:

1) setContentView(R.layout.fragment_all);

```
Error:(43, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
```

2) ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView);

```
   Error:(55, 40) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
```

3) ArrayAdapter adapter = new propertyArrayAdapter(this, 0, 
   rentalProperties);

```
Error:(52, 67) error: incompatible types: Menu1 cannot be converted to 
  Context
```

4) Intent intent = new Intent(Menu1.this, DetailActivity.class);

```
Error:(67, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for 
   Intent(Menu1,Class<DetailActivity>)
   constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
   (argument mismatch; Menu1 cannot be converted to String)
   constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
   (argument mismatch; Menu1 cannot be converted to Context)
```

The above given problems are rectified by answer given below, marked as answer. But here I face a problem with the layout. Layout is not fitting full to the screen, there is some blank space on every side. Tried different methods in layout, but no change. Layout code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="700dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="-10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/infoSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filename"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Filename"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.35" />

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_weight="2.35"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pricingSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/infoSection"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Status"
                    android:layout_width="172dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/status" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:text="Size:"
                    android:layout_weight="1.07" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="sz"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/size"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/size"
                    android:text="Progress:"
                    android:layout_weight="0.36" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="pg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/progress"
                    android:layout_weight="1.65" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Speed:"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progress"
                    android:layout_weight="0.87" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/speed"
                    android:layout_weight="1.86" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205732/converting-activity-into-fragment, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785049/converting-an-activity-to-a-fragment, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604802/how-to-change-activity-to-fragment, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment

Comment: in fragment `onCreateView` return view that must be show in `Fragment`, don't use `setContentView` in `Fragment`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry, I not so familiar with stackoverflow... Will try avoiding such mistakes next time. Thank you for notifying... @halter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) setContentView(R.layout.fragment_all);

For `fragment`, You have to inflate the view in `onCreateView()`. Do not use `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_all);` for `fragment`;

> 2) ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView);

You have to get the views as child of parent in fragments. In Below code `rootView` is the parent so I initiated `ListView` as:

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
```

> 3) ArrayAdapter adapter = new propertyArrayAdapter(this, 0,
>   rentalProperties);

You have to get the context of `activity` which holds the fragment:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new propertyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), 0, rentalProperties);
```

> 4) Intent intent = new Intent(Menu1.this, DetailActivity.class);

Replace this with:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
```

Finally move all the codes from `onCreate()` to `onCreateView()` as below:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);
        rentalProperties.add(new Property(10, "Smith Street", "Sydney", "NSW", "A large 3 bedroom apartment right in the heart of Sydney! A rare find, with 3 bedrooms and a secured car park.", 450.00, "property_image_1", 3, 1, 1, false));
        rentalProperties.add(new Property(66, "King Street", "Sydney", "NSW", "A fully furnished studio apartment overlooking the harbour. Minutes from the CBD and next to transport, this is a perfect set-up for city living.", 320.00, "property_image_2", 1, 1, 1, false));
        rentalProperties.add(new Property(1, "Liverpool Road", "Liverpool", "NSW", "A standard 3 bedroom house in the suburbs. With room for several cars and right next to shops this is perfect for new families.", 360.00, "property_image_3", 3, 2, 2, true));
        rentalProperties.add(new Property(567, "Sunny Street", "Gold Coast", "QLD", "Come and see this amazing studio apartment in the heart of the gold coast, featuring stunning waterfront views.", 360.00, "property_image_4" , 1, 1, 1, false));

        //create our new array adapter
        ArrayAdapter<Property> adapter = new propertyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), 0, rentalProperties);

        //Find list view and bind it with the custom adapter
        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.customListView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //add event listener so we can handle clicks
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener adapterViewListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Property property = rentalProperties.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("streetNumber", property.getStreetNumber());
                intent.putExtra("streetName", property.getStreetName());
                intent.putExtra("suburb", property.getSuburb());
                intent.putExtra("state", property.getState());
                intent.putExtra("image", property.getImage());

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
            }
        };
        //set the listener to the list view
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(adapterViewListener);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

1) `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_all);` in the fragment it replaced with return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);

2) `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView);`
replace it with : `ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.customListView);`

3) `ArrayAdapter adapter = new propertyArrayAdapter(this, 0, rentalProperties);`
replace it with `ArrayAdapter adapter = new propertyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), 0, rentalProperties); // getActivity() it's ur context`

4) `Intent intent = new Intent(Menu1.this, DetailActivity.class);`
replace it with 4) `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);`

Hope that help :)